# Is it necessary to "finalize upload" of Forge Design Automation outputs stored in OSS?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

The [blog post about migrating to Direct-to-S3](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach) says that although the Design Automation API is not affected, "if a workitem is saved to OSS, the application will need to finalize the upload inside the OnComplete callback."

The [step-by-step tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/) on the documentation site doesn't show this. The [Direct-to-S3 .NET samples](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-net-samples) blog post also doesn't mention this.

So far, the OnComplete callback has been an optional feature, and it is not always possible/feasible to implement (e.g. non-public web servers with tight restrictions on port forwarding, reverse proxies, etc). In those scenarios, polling has been an acceptable alternative, but even then, continuous polling has not been required. It seems that with the upload finalization being time-sensitive, we will be forced to either implement OnComplete callbacks or continuous polling in order to finalize uploads within an acceptable amount of time.

Is this accurate? Are Design Automation work items that store outputs to OSS going to require an application outside of Forge to finalize the upload of those outputs in all cases?

Comment: yes, you are right. With current mechanism of Design Automation, you have to finalize complete uploading of S3 signed url workflow explicitly.  OnComplete callback is the best choice because it notifies your endpoint when the job is done. If it does not accept with OnComplete, Polling is alterative while as you already know, you need to poll until it returns fail or success.

Comment: In addition, your job of Design Automation must finish within the lifetime of one S3 signed url (currently, max  1 hour), otherwise, when Design Automation tries to upload output to OSS storage, it will fail because the input signed url may have been expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the upload is only required when using the [Signed S3 Upload endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/) to generate the URLs for Design Automation outputs. An answer from [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73310198/how-can-i-increase-work-item-payload-limit-for-forge-design-automation-for-inven) (confirmed in comments on Zhong Wu's answer above) clarifies that the [Signed S3 Upload endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/) is not always required for Design Automation outputs being stored in OSS.

If the output files don't need to be in BIM 360 or ACC, the [Signed URL endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/) can be used instead, which does not require completing the upload (and also generates URLs that are much shorter).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right. With current mechanism of Design Automation, you have to finalize complete uploading of S3 signed url workflow explicitly. OnComplete callback is the best choice because it notifies your endpoint when the job is done. If it does not accept with OnComplete, Polling is alterative while as you already know, you need to poll until it returns fail or success.

In addition, your job of Design Automation must finish within the lifetime of one S3 signed url (currently, max 1 hour), otherwise, when Design Automation tries to upload output to OSS storage, it will fail because the input signed url may have been expired.

Comment: While implementing this in my application, I ran into an issue where the work item  payload becomes too large due to the much longer URLs that are generated by the [Signed S3 download](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3download-GET/) and [Signed S3 upload](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/) endpoints.

Comment: In looking for a solution to that new issue in a [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73310198/how-can-i-increase-work-item-payload-limit-for-forge-design-automation-for-inven/73311355#73311355), @jaime-rosales mentioned that I should use the [Signed URL endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/) instead. Since that endpoint does not return an upload key, it seems like I could use it and avoid having to complete the upload. Is that a valid alternative?

Comment: If your input or output files need to be in BIM 360 or ACC, then the endpoint(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/) Jaime suggested does not work, but if you are not playing files from BIM 360 or ACC, then the endpoint may be simple.