# How can I increase work item payload limit for Forge Design Automation for Inventor?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

I have updated the code I'm using to queue work items in Design Automation to use the [Direct to S3](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach) approach that is required starting next month. Due to this change, the URLs that are being sent in for outputs (where Design Automation will upload the outputs) are MUCH larger. As a result, I am getting a response with a 413 status code and an error message saying that the payload length exceeds the limit of 16384 bytes when I attempt to submit work items.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Signed URL endpoint with the query parameter of ***useCdn=true*** guarantees the payload goes through Direct to S3. Those urls are a lot shorter. What I'm doing is the following.

Upload to OSS (New approach)

1. [POST presigned URL to S3](https://GET%20buckets/:bucket_key/objects/:object_key/signeds3upload) (you can control in how long will it expire up to 60 mins, default is 2 mins)
2. Upload to presigned URL (no authorization is required since it is a presinged url)
3. Complete the upload calling [POST complete](https://POST%20buckets/:bucket_key/objects/:object_key/signeds3upload)

Then we need 1 url for Download (input to Design Automation) and 1 for Upload (output from Design Automation)

This is where we can use the [Signed URL endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/)

For the input will look something like this:

POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/signed?access=read&useCdn=true

For output will look like this:

POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/signed?access=write&useCdn=true

Both urls have an expiration time of 60 mins. I'm working on the update of the tutorials in Design Automation and also I have a collection that I will be blogging about it soon.

Comment: So the [Signed URL endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/) can be used for both downloading and uploading? That's good to know -- the docs only mention downloading. Why would I ever want to use the new [Signed S3 download](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3download-GET/) or [Signed S3 upload](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/) endpoints?

Comment: Also, since the [Signed URL endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/) does not return an upload key, I guess that means that the upload does not need to be finalized by my application after the work item completes?

Comment: I hope this is true (not requiring upload to be finalized), as this is the answer I was hoping for on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73253148/is-it-necessary-to-finalize-upload-of-forge-design-automation-outputs-stored-i). However, that conflicts with the answer from your colleague as well as the information in [this article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach)

Comment: This does work, and I appreciate your help.  To prevent others from being confused on this, it would be great if you could update your [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach) to clarify the "if a workitem is saved to OSS, the application will need to finalize the upload inside the OnComplete callback" statement. That is only needed if using the [Signed S3 upload endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/), correct?